# Detecting a "join" ZMQ

Tags: python, c, zeromq

I'll keep it short.
Using ZMQ to communicate between Python(server) and C ( client ). ( made a game )

The goal is to get the server side running only when the client connects.

Is there a way to detect something in ZeroMQ to start the program?

Answer (score 0):

> **Q** : *"Is there a way to detect something in ZeroMQ to start the program?"*

I'll keep it short.

Yes, there is.

> read all details in the published API about using the `socket_monitor()` for handling this and similar events. Definitely doable & easy to integrate
> You will soon fall in love with the ZeroMQ's smart tools & the designed-in art of the Zen of Zero
> Definitely a good pick :o)